# Creating a a grid of ggplots with table grob of values below

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, gtable

I am trying to create an errorbar plot in ggplot with a table of values. Additionally, I am trying to place this into a grid. These are for linear regression values and confidence intervals.

I have the following:

```
point<- c(1:10)
ciupper <- seq(2,20,2)
cilower <- seq(.1,1,10)
year <- c("2005/06", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015")
label <-c(quote("Ref"),bquote("val 1"),bquote("val 2"),bquote("val 3"),bquote("val 4"),bquote("val 5"), 
bquote("val 6"), bquote("val 7"), bquote("val 8"), bquote("val 9"))
data9 <- data.frame(point, cilower, ciupper, year)
tabl9 <- data.frame(year, label)

quant9 <- ggplot(data=data9, aes(x=year, y=point))
+ geom_point(size=3)
+ geom_errorbar(ymax=ciupper, ymin=cilower, width=0.1) 
+ geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") 
+ ylim(-5, 30) + labs(x="", y="", title="Title") + theme_pubr() + labs_pubr()
quant9

attend <- ggarrange(quant9, quant9, quant9, labels="AUTO")
annotate_figure(attend, top=text_grob("Title", size=20), 
left=text_grob("X Axis", size=20, rot=90), bottom=text_grob("Year", size=20))
```

which gives me this:
[image: Grid of GGplots]

I want to add a table of the actual values below each graph. I have been using tableGrob:

```
tt <- ttheme_default(padding =unit(c(6,4), "mm"))
tb9 <- tableGrob(t(tabl9), theme=tt, rows=NULL)

test <- grid.arrange(quant9,tb9,nrow = 2,ncol=1)
```

Through messing around with `widths` settings I was able to finally achieve a close match of the grob to one of the plots, but once I tried to put that into the grid everything was distorted.

Can someone help me figure out how to elegantly get the values to sit neatly right below the graph, and then do that for each graph and put that into a grid for display?

Comment: I don't know of a way to add the tables that doesn't involve manual fiddling, though it's probably possible to automate it if you know enough about how to access internal grob coordinates of the plots. Another option is to use `geom_text` instead of `geom_point` and avoid the use of tables of values: `geom_text(aes(label=point), size=3) +
  geom_errorbar(ymax=ciupper, ymin=cilower, width=0.1, size=0.2, linetype="11", colour="red") + ...`

Comment: Or, place the values on the plot panel, but below the lowest point of the error bars. For example, add the following to your plot (where I've rounded the labels on the assumption that your actual use case involves decimal numbers rather than integers): `+   geom_text(aes(label=sprintf("%1.1f", point), y=-1), size=3)`.

Comment: The tinkering around with TableGrob is frustrating and while pretty, ultimately unsuccessful. I wish there was a way to make pretty tables in ggplot and link them to graphs. I tried your method and it is not perfect, but ultimately achieves was I was aiming for while looking good. Thanks!

Comment: As a note I actually went a bit further and used geom_rect (to make a gray background), geom_segment (to add vertical white lines on the background color), and added an additional geom_hline (to essentially greate a box) so as to re-create a tableGrob using he geom_text option you illustrated above. Ends up working really nicely.

Answer (score 0):

To make grids of plots you have to specify before them

```
par(mfrow=(nrows, ncols)
```

then each plot you will generate will be added by row in a nrow*ncols grid.

To set graphical parameters back to default, type at the end of your plotting

```
par(mfrow=(1,1))
```